# Exclude a set of specific numbers in a "\d+" regular expression pattern

Tags: regex

Let's say I have some strings :

```
some50
some51/x
some52/y
some53/z
some510
some511/x
some512/y
some513/z
```

I want to test if my string are in the form `some` + a number + anything.

I use for this requirement the pattern : `^some\d+`, which is returning me all matches.

Now I have a requirement to exclude some of the numbers. For example, I have to exclude 51 and 52 from the matches. What is the correct expression ?

I've tried (more a guess than a try I admit):

- `^some(\d+|(?!(51|52)))`
- `^some((\d+)(?!(51|52)))`
- `^some(\d+)^(?!(51|52)))`
- `^some(\d+)(?!(51|52)))`

but none of the them are returning the expected result, which is :

```
some50
some53/z
some510
some511/x
some512/y
some513/z
```

PS: don't know if it matters, but the regex is used within a PowerShell script.

**[Edit]** Extended the questions to show that 51x should not be excluded

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for a negative lookahead assertion. I'm not familiar with PowerShell script, but in perl compatible regex this works:

```
^some(?!(51$|52$))\d+$
```

This will also not match `some510`. If that's not intended, remove the `$` after `51` and `52`

update: changing from string-boundary to word-boundary (at the end of the string)

```
^some(?!(51\b|52\b))\d+\b
```

Comment: According to http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html, PowerShell uses the .NET flavor of regular expressions, and so lookaheads are indeed supported. +1

Comment: This is nearly working. I removed the $ because there is leading characters. The regex is then `^some(?!(51|52))\d+` The only remaining issue, is that 510 or 520 is also excluded. I've updated my question to show what I meant.

Comment: @SteveB: ok, then change the `$` to `\b` to match word boundaries.

Answer (score -1):

Here's one way, probably not the most elegant:
`^some([0-46-9]\d*|5([03-9]|\d\d+)|5)`