# How to find multiple lines without specific number

Tags: c#, regex

I have these lines:

```
MyString                 33
MyString                 10
MyString                 3
MyString                 5
```

I want to get match on all the lines that doesn't have the specific number: 3.
Therefore, I need to get match on these numbers:

```
MyString                 33
MyString                 10
MyString                 5
```

But **not** on:

```
MyString                 3
```

This is what I tried:

```
MyString                 ^(?!3)
MyString                 ^(3)
MyString                 (^?!3)
MyString                 (^3)
```

But none of them worked.
I don't have much experience with regex.
I used this website for as a guide:
https://www.cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

I also read similar questions:
[Exclude certain numbers from range of numbers using Regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35592438/exclude-certain-numbers-from-range-of-numbers-using-regular-expression)
[Exclude a set of specific numbers in a "\d+" regular expression pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12531960/exclude-a-set-of-specific-numbers-in-a-d-regular-expression-pattern)

But I still didn't understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the regex

```
MyString                 (?!3\b)\d+
```

see the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iBgQI4/3/)

Negative Lookahead (?!3\b) 
Assert that the Regex below does not match the character 3 literally 
\b assert position at a word boundary

Comment: I think `\b` or `$` are better than of `\n`. What do you think?

Comment: I ran it on large file, and the "\n" did some problems (receiving match on lines with "3") but after you edit it with "\b" it seems to work good. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A working solution:

`\w+\s+(?!3\b)\d+`

```
\w+      # 1 or more word characters
\s+      # 1 or more white-space characters
(?!3\b)  # looking ahead, this group may not match (\b is a word boundary)
\d+      # 1 or more digits
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YPlTPd/1)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression:

```
grep -v '^3$' yourFile
```

In this way, you are asking to find:

1. All strings starting (^) with 3
2. All strings terminating ($) with 3
3. All strings that have only one 3 in them

From this, you have selected all the strings containing only the number 3. Reverse selection with the flag -v to get what you want.

Hope it helps.